# Flutter how to add box-shadow or drop-shadow onto text input field?

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't think this is possible but thought I would ask and see if anyone has a solution for this I want to add box-shadow or drop-shadow onto the text input field but I don't want it to get messed up when using error text or hint text. Attached screenshot showing the issue. I tried Material, Physical Mode, Container still getts messed I don't think there is a way as error text is inside the input widget, and once it shows the height grows.

[image]

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most elegant way, but you could tinker with something like this:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 40.0,
      width: 200.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
              spreadRadius: 4,
              blurRadius: 12,
              offset: Offset(0, 8),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      width: 200.0,
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          hintText: 'Name',
          errorText: 'Field cannot be empty',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Thank but I have looked at using stack the issue it doesn't really look good and what happens if the inner elements scales to screen size I feel that would create issues

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe You Could Try This One

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 16, top: 8),
          child: Container(
            height: 48,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red.shade300,
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
              boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6),
                  blurRadius: 8,
                  offset: const Offset(4, 4),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: InkWell(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                onTap: () {
                  yourfunction();
                },
                child: Center(
                  child: loadingButton
                      ? SizedBox(
                          height: 30.0,
                          width: 30.0,
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            valueColor:
                                AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.white),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Text(
                          'Apply',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: @AlmogKoren oh I'm so sorry. I think I misrepresented your question.